# Is there any way to subscribe and to listen feed in boost beast websocket?

Tags: boost, boost-beast, poloniex, beast-websockets, boost-beast-websocket

I am using an example from [boost beast documentation for async websocket client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp). The to send some command to subscribe and then to listen feed until it is terminated manually (preferably with other function or else)

Standard examples aren't applied as either it gives no response or it doesn't give permanent feed.

For references Poloniex Websocket API needs to be accessed.

Is there any example of listening to feed permanently?

Comment: Yes. /padding /padding /padding

Comment: Please provide more information or a snippet of the code or a documentation.

Comment: Precisely. You should do that. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @sehe is this enough information to answer?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to not stop "listening" (and by listening you really just mean reading).

In synchronous code, you just loop the read operation.

In async code, you make it a chain. The echo examples in Asio show this (in several ways).

In this [async websocket example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp) you'd change the `on_read` completion handler

```
void
on_read(
    beast::error_code ec,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if(ec)
        return fail(ec, "read");

    // Close the WebSocket connection
    ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal,
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &session::on_close,
            shared_from_this()));
}
```

To replace `async_close` with more `async_read`s e.g.

```
    // Read a message into our buffer
    ws_.async_read(
        buffer_,
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &session::on_read,
            shared_from_this()));
```